# How do I write and read data in a browser with a COM port?

Tags: javascript, serial-port, port

I am trying to read and write data from hardware through the browser.

Here's what the hardware does:
Send --> Data is simply sent from the unit.
Writing --> I write data and when the data is sent correctly, the unit sends back a receive signal. This means that I must first send and then read directly what the device returns as a response.

Global variables:

```
var flag= false;
var port;
```

Reading method

```
//Reads data from the Hardware
function readDataFromHardware(time) {
    // Checks if the browser can open the serial Port
    if  ("serial" in navigator) {
        hardwareData= '';
        readData();


        async function readData()
        {
            if (flag == false)
            {
                port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
                await port.open({ baudRate: 115200, dataBits: 8, stopBits: 1, parity: "none"});
                flag = true;
            }


            //Send "R" to hardware to get data
            const encoder = new TextEncoder();
            const writer = port.writable.getWriter();
            await writer.write(encoder.encode("R"));
            writer.releaseLock();


            //Wait 1 second and read Port
            setTimeout(async function () {
                const reader = port.readable.getReader();

                try {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        const { value, done } = await reader.read();
                        if (done)
                        {
                            console.log('LOCK');
                            reader.releaseLock();
                            break;
                        }
                        if (value)
                        {
                            // do somthing...
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (error)
                {
                
                }
            }, time);
        }
    }
}
```

Writing method

```
function writeData() 
{
    if ("serial" in navigator) 
    {
        hardwareData = '';
        var outputString = getStringtoSend();
        writeDataAsync();


        async function writeDataAsync() {
            if (flag == false) {
                port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
                await port.open({ baudRate: 115200, dataBits: 8, stopBits: 1, parity: "none" });
                flag = true;
            }

            //Send "W" to hardware so that the device is ready to receive the data
            const encoder = new TextEncoder();
            const writer = port.writable.getWriter();
            await writer.write(encoder.encode("W"));

            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                writer.write(encoder.encode(outputString));
                writer.write(encoder.encode("\r"));
                writer.releaseLock();

                proofIfDataSent();
            },300);
        }
    }
}
```

If the dtaen have been received correctly, the device returns a feedback value to see if the values have been received, this is the proofIfDataSent(); method.

```
async function proofIfDataSent()
{
    setTimeout(async function () 
    {
        const reader = port.readable.getReader();

        try {
            while (true) {
                const { value, done } = await reader.read();
                if (done) {
                    reader.releaseLock();
                }
                if (value) {
                    // do somthing...
                }
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

The methods work individually if I, for example, only read or only write. My goal is that as soon as I have selected the port I can read and write as well. However, I get the following error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'getReader' on
> 'ReadableStream': ReadableStreamDefaultReader constructor can only
> accept readable streams that are not yet locked to a reader

Comment: Sounds like synchronization issue, you are waiting  for _nn_ sec instead of waiting until result received with _nn_ sec timeout...

Comment: Yes, but if I use the methods individually, only write or only read, it works without problems. So I would have said that the taiming is correct or what do you think?

Comment: Since you didn't post the actual code how you execute all this, nor where the error is actually coming from, I can only assume that you are trying read from `port` while it still locked, because all unlocking is happening after _nn_ timeout. So, try increase the delay before executing the function that gives you the error, at least this will tell you if it's sync issue or not.

Comment: I have just tried this and the same error. When debugging, the proofIfDataSent method is not executed or catches an error there. To be exact, the error happens in the method  proofIfDataSent --> const reader = port.readable.getReader();